# The logics of the creation of aggregated features with featuretools

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-engineering, featuretools

I have a dataset what contains several columns, including `date`, `instance_id`, `numerical_x` and `categorical_y`. I use `featuretools` package for feature generation as it has powerful ability to take time shifts into account.

What I want to get is feature like `mean(numerical_x groupby categorical_y)` and merge it to the main frame on `categorical_y` column. And I am guessing how to create it with `featuretools` by itself - how my EntitySet should look like, what feature primitives should be included and etc?

Answer (score 1):

Featuretools has a primitive `CumMean` that can be used as a groupby primitive along with extra `primitive_options` parameters to dfs to get just the exact feature you're describing. An example in the Featuretools documentation showing what that looks like can be seen [here](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/latest/guides/specifying_primitive_options.html?highlight=groupby#Specifying-GroupBy-Options).

For the situation you're describing, if sounds like your EntitySet should be created to look something like this if you have a dataframe `df`:

```py
es = EntitySet()
es.add_dataframe(dataframe_name="my_dataframe", 
                 dataframe=df,
                 index="instance_id"
)
```

Then your DFS call can be made like this:

```py
fm, f = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
       target_dataframe_name='my_dataframe',
       agg_primitives=[],
       trans_primitives=[],
       groupby_trans_primitives=['cum_mean'],
       primitive_options={
           'cum_mean': {'include_groupby_columns': {'my_dataframe': ['categorical_y']},
                        'include_columns': {'my_dataframe': ['numerical_x']}
                       }
       })
```